# SwiftUI: ListViews inside TabBar inside NavigationView generates empty View

Tags: ios, listview, swiftui, navigationview, tabview

I have two `ListView` inside a `TabView` which is in turn inside a `NavigationView`.

When I run this code and i scroll the `ListView` content i see there's an empty view being generated that seems to be on top of `ListView` rows.

When the list view is scrolled all the way to the top it totally covers the first item.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var gibsonGuitars = [ Guitar(id: 1, name: "Les Paul")]
    @State private var fenderGuitars = [ Guitar(id: 1, name: "Stratorcaster")]
    @State private var selectedView = 0

    private let brandGibson = "Gibson Guitars"
    private let brandFender = "Fender Guitars"

    private var title: String {
        $selectedView.wrappedValue == 0 ? brandGibson : brandFender
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedView) {
                GuitarListView(guitars: $gibsonGuitars)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "guitars")
                        Text(brandGibson)
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                GuitarListView(guitars: $fenderGuitars)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "guitars")
                        Text(brandFender)
                    }
                    .tag(1)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(title))
            GuitarDetail()
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())

    }
}

struct Guitar: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct GuitarListView: View {
    @Binding var guitars: [Guitar]
    var body: some View {
        List(guitars) { guitar in
            Text(guitar.name)
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct GuitarDetail: View {
    @State var guitar: Guitar?
    var body: some View {
        guard let guitar = guitar else {
            return Text("No Guitar Selected.")
        }
        return Text("\(guitar.name)").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

What is it? How do i avoid it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this was caused by my lack of understanding about the safe areas in SwiftUI. I was able to fix it by adding `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var gibsonGuitars = [ Guitar(id: 1, name: "Les Paul")]
    @State private var fenderGuitars = [ Guitar(id: 2, name: "Stratorcaster")]
    @State private var selectedView = 0

    private let brandGibson = "Gibson"
    private let brandFender = "Fender"

    private var title: String {
        $selectedView.wrappedValue == 0 ? brandGibson : brandFender
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedView) {
                    GuitarListView(guitars: $gibsonGuitars)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "guitars")
                            Text(brandGibson)
                        }
                        .tag(0)
                    GuitarListView(guitars: $fenderGuitars)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "guitars")
                        Text(brandFender)
                    }
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .navigationBarTitle(title)
            GuitarDetail()
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct Guitar: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct GuitarListView: View {
    @Binding var guitars: [Guitar]
    var body: some View {
        List(guitars) { guitar in
            Text(guitar.name)
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct GuitarDetail: View {
    @State var guitar: Guitar?
    var body: some View {
        guard let guitar = guitar else {
            return Text("No Guitar Selected.")
        }
        return Text("\(guitar.name)").font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```